# Limit consecutive characters on keypress with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, html

i wrote this code for an information booth at a park, it works on html5 and javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var nameFilter = /^(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]+$/g;        
    if(nameFilter.test(name)) {
      $('#name').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
          $(this).unbind(e).keypress();
        }
        else {
          e.preventDefault();
          //return false;
        }
          });
    }
};
```

it is supposed to prevent more than one consecutive characters (the booth keyboard is kinda broken and on key press it puts like 3 to 5 times the pressed key)

so far i've accomplished to limit it to two characters, but then thanks to preventDefault() it does nothing, i used an unbind to restore it but still i've accomplished nothing and i need help with this, whether it be by this mean of any other

Comment: If this is on an input field, simply listen to a `change` event and filter any duplicate consecutive characters rather than binding to the keypresses? Why do you need to prevent consecutive characters, what's the use case, since there might be a better way of doing this?

Comment: What if duplicate consecutive characters are legitimate, like the r's in Harris?  It simply seems like it's time for a new keyboard

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your method. The regex test is outside of your on keypress. Also you are testing for only two types of keycodes, not consecutive characters. The in your if statement, you are triggering a keypress, which would do nothing since you have unbound it.

Comment: The need for this is because is an on-screen keyboard and everytime you press a key it puts 3 to 5 times that letter, let's say you type "hello", the keyboard types "hhheellllloooo", i just want to limit it to one character per press, it's used mostly for names so there's no big issue with just one character being or not legitimate

Comment: What about using on key up instead ?

Answer (score 0):

This version accounts for capitalizing letters with the shift key

```
var nameElement = $('#name');
var wasShiftKeyPressed;
var nameAfterFirstKeyDown;

nameElement.keydown(function(e) {
    wasShiftKeyPressed = e.shiftKey;
    setTimeout(function() {
        nameAfterFirstKeyDown = nameAfterFirstKeyDown ? nameAfterFirstKeyDown : nameElement.val();
    });
})

nameElement.keyup(function() {
    if (wasShiftKeyPressed) {
        wasShiftKeyPressed = false;
        nameAfterFirstKeyDown = nameElement.val(); //Otherwise capitalization only works for first letter
    }
    else {
        nameElement.val(nameAfterFirstKeyDown);
        nameAfterFirstKeyDown = "";
    }
});
```